# Angular 4 error when I block routing with a guard

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 project I need to block some rouing based on the user logged roles.
So in my routing guard I have a function that retrieve the logged user roles and check if the page allow this role, and if the page is not allowed I need to route to 403 page and I return an `observable.of(false)`.
But now in console I see an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>   TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I need to return `Observable<boolean>` to my canActivateChild function, I need to use this version and not the `:boolean` version

This is the function in the guard.ts

```
if (SidebarComponent.roles === undefined) {
          console.log('SidebarComponent.roles UNDEFINED')
          return this.authenticationService.getLoggedUser()
          .flatMap((res) => {
              console.log(res)
              SidebarComponent.roles = res.body.roles
              if (SidebarComponent.roles.includes(this.translateRole(role))) {
                   console.log('ALLOWED')
                   return Observable.of(true);
               } else {
                    this.routeToUnauthorized();
                    }
              })


  routeToUnauthorized() {
    this.router.navigate(['/403']);
    console.log('role NOT allowed')
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
```

And this is the loggedUser function that retrieve the info about logged user(roles)

```
  getLoggedUser() {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('projection', 'withWorkShift')

    return this.endPointUrlService.checkIfMapIsReady(this.entityLink[0])
      .flatMap((res) => {

        return this.http.get(this.endPointUrlService.cutLinks(this.endPointUrlService.mapNames.get('usersSearchMap')
          .get(this.entityLink[0].endPoints[0])), {observe: 'response', params: params})
          .map((response) => <any>response);
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return an Observable in your flatMap

```
...     
} else {
     return this.routeToUnauthorized(); <- here
}
```

you just forgot the return statement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve it using promises.

```
interface IUserPacket {
    /*  define an user interface */
    body: IRoles[]
}

interface IRoles {
    /* Define your roles interface */
}


@Injectable()
export class IsAuthorized implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

    public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        const promise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {

            if (SidebarComponent.roles === undefined) {

                this.authenticationService.getLoggedUser().then((userPacket: IUserPacket) => {
                    userPacket.body.roles

                });

                SidebarComponent.roles = res.body.roles
                if (SidebarComponent.roles.includes(this.translateRole(role))) {
                    console.log('ALLOWED')
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/403']);
                    console.log('role NOT allowed')
                    resolve(false);
                    // reject();
                }
            }
        });

        return promise;
    }

    private getLoggedUser(): Promise<IUserPacket> {
        return new Promise<IUser>((resolve, reject) => {
            const params = new HttpParams().set('projection', 'withWorkShift')

            const url = this.endPointUrlService.cutLinks(this.endPointUrlService.mapNames.get('usersSearchMap'))

            return this.http.get(url).map(resolve);
        })
    }
}
```